# Pushing docker image to docker hub private repository return authentication error

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I have built a test image and tried to push it to docker hub's private repository. I was able to login with "docker login" and the credential gets stored in .dockercfg file. However, when I am trying to push the image with "docker push accountname/repositoryname" command it then returns the following error.

> 36423578012b: Image push failed
>   FATA[0006] Error pushing to registry: Authentication is required.

What is the proper way to push to docker hub's private repository?

Docker version:

> Client version: 1.6.0
>   Client API version: 1.18
>   Go version (client): go1.4.2
>   Git commit (client): 4749651
>   OS/Arch (client): darwin/amd64
>   Server version: 1.6.0

Comment: What OS and what docker version are you using? It seems to have been fixed in 1.6 (https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/12910#issuecomment-98139325)

Comment: updated with docker version

Comment: Are you trying to push to an Automated Build repository?

Comment: yes that's correct, am i not suppose to do that? the repo will build a new image when a commit goes into my bitbucket repo.

Comment: arhh that's it ! can't push to automated build repo.

Comment: Yes, you got it. You are not allowed to push to the Automated Build repository.